# asp:Image ImageUrl calling function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net-2010

I'm converting VB.NET code into C#. The following code doesn't work in C#. Can someone please help with Syntax. I have tried ImageUrl='<%=setImage(#Eval("TPU")) %>' still no luck.

The issue, it doesn't call the setImage() function in the code behind. I get the following error:
The best overloaded method for myPage.setImage(string) has some invalid arguments.
Argument '1":cannot be convert from 'object' to 'string'

### aspx page

```
<asp:Image ID="img1" ImageUrl='<%#setImage(Eval("TPU")) %>' runat="server" />
```

### C# code

```
public string setImage(string status) {

 if (status == "Running") { 
return "images/run.jpg";
else if (status == "Unknown") {
return "images/unknown.jpg"
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what does "code doesn't work" mean.  Are you getting an error? or does it simply not show what you are expecting?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing bracket on the first condition. Secondly, it doesn't look like you even need the else condition.

This should work fine, assuming that the image paths are correct:

```
public string setImage(string status) 
{
    //if status is running return the run image
    if (status == "Running")  
        return "images/run.jpg";

    //otherwise return the unknown image
    return "images/unknown.jpg"; 
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, you need to cast the value as a string in your markup:

```
ImageUrl='<%# setImage((string)Eval("TPU")) %>'
```

Comment: The issue, it doesn't call the setImage() function in the code behind. I get the following error: The best overloaded method for myPage.setImage(string) has some invalid arguments. Argument '1":cannot be convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: @user1385570: Updated my answer. You need to cast the value to a string.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working. Don't forget to accept if you're satisfied.

Comment: Some time I got annoyed by new users behavior. In this case poster got his answer from you but he did not accept your answer. Most of the time new users ask question and never reply. What you think?

Comment: @jams: I agree. It's not that I necessarily care about the reputation, but it leaves questions unresolved, or seemingly unresolved, when the poster doesn't mark the correct answer. The question and answer become less valuable to future viewers.

Comment: yes I 100% agree  with you. For it want to give you one more +1 but sad, I can only do it once (which I have done already).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public string setImage(string status) 
{   
string imgurl=(status == "Running")?"~//images//run.jpg":"~//images/unknown.jpg";
return imgurl;
}
```

Updated

```
<asp:Image ID="img1" ImageUrl='<%#setImage(Eval("TPU").ToString()) %>' runat="server" />
```

Comment: The issue, it doesn't call the setImage() function in the code behind. I get the following error: The best overloaded method for myPage.setImage(string) has some invalid arguments. Argument '1":cannot be convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: @user1385570 : Now try with `ToString()` method.

Comment: @jams: I'm not trying to nitpick here, but that code still won't compile. Not all the code paths return a value...

Comment: @James Johnson: You mean `ToString()` method will not work we need to `cast` it?

Comment: No, that part was fine. Your function was incorrect, but it looks like you corrected it, so +1.